# Finding matrices that satisfy a quadratic matrix equation and their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slGWl.png)

Hello everyone,

I am currently working on a problem where I need to find all square matrices A that satisfy the quadratic matrix equation A^2 - 3A + 2I = 0, and then find their inverses. I understand that this is a quadratic equation in terms of A, and it can be rewritten as (A - I)(A - 2I) = 0, which gives us two potential matrices that satisfy the condition: A = I and A = 2I.

I also understand that the inverse of the identity matrix I is I itself, and the inverse of the matrix 2I is 1/2 * I. However, I am not completely confident in these answers and I would appreciate if someone could confirm if I am on the right track.

Additionally, if there are other matrices that satisfy the given condition, could you please help me understand how to find them and their inverses?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Comment: Any (square) matrix with simple eigenvalues contained in the set $\{1,2\}$ will satisfy that quadratic equation. As for the inverse, rewrite the equation as $I=(1/2)A(3I-A)$.

Comment: If $B$ is a projection, i.e. $B^2=B,$ then $A=I+B$ satisfies the equation. The converse holds as well. Next $A=(I-B)+2B,$ so $A^{-1}=(I-B)+{1\over 2}B.$